# $x = x' \pmod N$ iff $N$ divides $x - x'$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, definition

This is one of the first lines in one of my lecture notes, where they write:

> $x = x' \pmod N$ if and only if $N$ divides $x - x'$

I've taken a discrete maths course a while ago but this doesn't make much sense to me. I can't remember seeing $x'$ anywhere. If anyone can dumb this down or link a youtube video I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the definition of mod. $x$ and $x^{\prime}$ are arbitrary.
For example,
$$
7\equiv3\mod4.
$$
In this case, $x=7$ and $x^{\prime}=3$. You can check that the above
is true (with respect to the definition you are given) by noting that
$x-x^{\prime}=7-3=4$ is divisible by $4$.

Comment: Oh man, thanks! I don't know why x' through me for a loop so much.

Comment: I had to wait the standard 10 minutes(?) before accepting...

Answer (score 1):

That's a *definition*.

Perhaps using other letters helps:

> Given integers, $a,b,n$, we say that $a \equiv b \bmod n$ when $n$ divides $a − b$.

The notation is suggestive of equality and it does share many of its properties, especially with respect to arithmetic. This suggestive notation is due to Gauss.

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) for examples and further explanations.

Answer (score 1):

It's a lot less mystical than you might think. You have one number called $x$, and you have another, a priori completely unrelated number called $x'$ (it could've been called $y$ or $a$ or $\xi$ or something else, but this time it's called $x'$), and your notes contain the *definition* of what the statement "$x\equiv x'\mod N$" *means*.

Answer (score 0):

If its the notation you xan replace $x^{\prime}$ with $y$.

Some people like to think of modulus as a "remainder function, and if that might be the way you originally learned it:

If $x$ and $y$ have the same remainder when divided by $N$, then $Nk+r=x$ and $Nl+r=y$ for integers $k,l$. So when you subtract them, $x-y=Nk+r-Nl-r=N(k-l)$, so the result will divide n. But to have the same remainder means they are congruent mod $N$

You can easily prove that intuitively "having the same remainder" and this definition are equivalent.